# How Do You Make The Size of a Circle bigger in Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've been making game that includes a head. I do not know how to make it bigger. Here is the code:

```
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.color('white')
head.shape('circle')
head.size(12)
head.penup()
```

Comment: if you would read documetation for [turtle.shape](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.shape) then you would see `turtle.shapesize()`

Answer (score 0):

See [turtle.shapesize()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.shapesize)

```
import turtle

head = turtle.Turtle()
head.shape('circle')
head.shapesize(12)

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the wrong function, instead of turtle.size() try using turtle.shapesize()

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `turtle.shapesize()` on line 5 it wont work if you use `turtle.size()`